# How do you extract the 4th index number from a function in python

Tags: python

I am trying to extract a number from this:

```
reciept = print("the quantity:",List2,"the product:", "{0} {1}" .format(product,f.readline())) 
#it prints the stock details for the product a user asks.
```

How do I extract a particular element from this line? When I try using something like:

```
reciept[3] or print( " {1}" .format(product,f.readline([2])))
```

It comes up as an error saying tuple index not allowed. Also, it doesn't print one element but half of the line which I don't want. 
Please help.

I have a stockfile which has the current stock levels for 6 product codes. that code, matches the user entered code with what the stock file has an displays the code, product title, current stock level and target stock level. I want to now extract the current stock level from all the values displayed, which i cannot do.
the stock file looks like this:

```
GTIN        PRODUCT     PP     CSL  TSL RSL
12345670    cupcakes    1.50    50  50  25
98765432    cakes       1.00    50  50  25
12121212    toffees     0.50    50  50  25
09090909    cement      1.00    50  50  25
56565656    phones      3.00    50  50  25
12321323    craters     2.00    50  50  25
```

so, how can I extract the CSL from a GTIN the user enters?

Comment: `print()` will return nothing. So you variable `reciept` will be equal to `nul` value.

Answer (score 3):

`print()` does not return anything, so the value of `reciept` is `None`, which is of course not indexable.

As to what you're asking:

```
with open('path/to/stockfile') as in_file:
    lookup_dict = {x.split()[0]: x.split()[3] for x in in_file}

csl = lookup_dict['98765432']
```

Comment: I have a stockfile which has the current stock levels for 6 product codes. that code, matches the user entered code with what the stock file has an displays the code, product title, current stock level and target stock level. I want to now extract the current stock level from all the values displayed, which i cannot do.

Comment: can you post an exemplary line from the file?

Comment: okay now we are getting somewhere. These are whitespace seperated i presume. I'll put a snippet in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have an input file called `input_file` like this:

```
GTIN        PRODUCT     PP     CSL  TSL RSL
12345670    cupcakes    1.50    50  50  25
98765432    cakes       1.00    50  50  25
12121212    toffees     0.50    50  50  25
09090909    cement      1.00    50  50  25
56565656    phones      3.00    50  50  25
12321323    craters     2.00    50  50  25
```

The first thing comes to my mind is to wrap your input_file into a dict.

So, here is my answer to your question:

```
def format_input(input_file = ""):
    data, id_dict = {}, 1
    aa = list(j for i in tuple(open(input_file, 'r')) for j in i.split(" ") if j != "")

    for i in range (6, len(aa), 6): # range from the 6th pisition with step = 6
        if i + 5 <= len(aa):
            data[id_dict] = {
                aa[0]: aa[i],
                aa[1]: aa[i+1],
                aa[2]: aa[i+2],
                aa[3]: aa[i+3],
                aa[4]: aa[i+4],
                aa[5].replace("\n", ""): aa[i+5].replace("\n", "")
                }
            id_dict +=1
        else:
            break # If something goes wrong
    return data
```

Output:

```
print(format_input("input_file"))

{
  1: 
   {
     'PP': '1.50',
     'RSL': '25',
     'PRODUCT': 'cupcakes',
     'TSL': '50',
     'CSL': '50',
     'GTIN': '12345670'
  }, 
  2: 
    {
     'PP': '1.00', 
     'RSL': '25', 
     'PRODUCT': 'cakes', 
     'TSL': '50', 
     'CSL': '50', 
     'GTIN': '98765432'
 }, 
 3: 
   {
    'PP': '0.50', 
    'RSL': '25', 
    'PRODUCT': 'toffees', 
    'TSL': '50', 
    'CSL': '50', 
    'GTIN': '12121212'
 }, 
 4: 
   {
    'PP': '1.00', 
    'RSL': '25', 
    'PRODUCT': 'cement', 
    'TSL': '50', 
    'CSL': '50', 
    'GTIN': '09090909'
 }, 
 5: 
   {
    'PP': '3.00', 
    'RSL': '25', 
    'PRODUCT': 'phones', 
    'TSL': '50', 
    'CSL': '50', 
    'GTIN': '56565656'
 }, 
 6: 
   {
    'PP': '2.00', 
    'RSL': '25', 
    'PRODUCT': 'craters', 
    'TSL': '50', 
    'CSL': '50', 
    'GTIN': '12321323'
   }
```

}

Now, if you want to access to your data, you can do like this example:

```
data = format_input("input_file")
for i in data:
    print("GTIN: {0} | PRODUCT: {1} | PP: {2} | CSL: {3} | TSL: {4} | RSL: {5}".format(
    data[i]["GTIN"], data[i]["PRODUCT"], data[i]["PP"], data[i]["CSL"], data[i]["TSL"], data[i]["RSL"]))
```

Output:

```
GTIN: 12345670 | PRODUCT: cupcakes | PP: 1.50 | CSL: 50 | TSL: 50 | RSL: 25
GTIN: 98765432 | PRODUCT: cakes | PP: 1.00 | CSL: 50 | TSL: 50 | RSL: 25
GTIN: 12121212 | PRODUCT: toffees | PP: 0.50 | CSL: 50 | TSL: 50 | RSL: 25
GTIN: 09090909 | PRODUCT: cement | PP: 1.00 | CSL: 50 | TSL: 50 | RSL: 25
GTIN: 56565656 | PRODUCT: phones | PP: 3.00 | CSL: 50 | TSL: 50 | RSL: 25
GTIN: 12321323 | PRODUCT: craters | PP: 2.00 | CSL: 50 | TSL: 50 | RSL: 25
```

**PS:** Sorry for the long answer. And maybe my answer is'nt the best one, but it may help you.

Comment: Since my stockfile's name is StockFile.txt, I would replace the first sentence with def format_input( StockFile.txt = ""): right? and also when i try to output it, the program just displays --- {} ---- instead of the file. Any idea why? Really appreciate your help by the way, thank you :)

Comment: If your input file which is StockFile.txt has the same input like what you added into your question, you can add the function `def format_input()` like what i've write into my answer. Then you'll use only `data = format_input("input_file")` and range into it and print the data you want to print it. if you can't do it i can update my answer to fill your needs.

Comment: also, could you add explanatory comments?

Comment: format_input() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given